# using Ansible on a gcp instance to connect to another instance error

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, ansible

I have a server called master-instance-node and a server called slave-instance-node-1. In the master-instance-node I have Ansible installed, I modified the /etc/ansible/hosts file and added the following

```
[webservers]
slave-instance-node-1
```

Then I try the following command

`ansible webservers -a "w " -u USERNAME` but I get the following error:

```
slave-instance-node-1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nThe ECDSA host key for slave-instance-node-1 has changed,\r\nand the key for the corresponding IP address XX.XXX.X.XX\r\nis unknown. This could either mean that\r\nDNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host\r\nand its host key have changed at the same time.\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nIT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!\r\nSomeone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!\r\nIt is also possible that a host key has just been changed.\r\nThe fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is\nSHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.\r\nPlease contact your system administrator.\r\nAdd correct host key in /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.\r\nOffending ECDSA key in /home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:1\r\n  remove with:\r\n  ssh-keygen -f \"/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts\" -R \"slave-instance-node-1\"\r\nECDSA host key for slave-instance-node-1 has changed and you have requested strict checking.\r\nHost key verification failed.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I thought the known hosts file is updated automatically in GCP. What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your slave-instance-node-1 was probably redeployed after you once connected from master-instance-node and its host key has changed. One solution is in the error message: `remove with:  ssh-keygen -f "/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "slave-instance-node-1"`. You can also set the env var `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false` when running ansible to disable host key checking when you know it has changed or your are connecting to a new unknown host. Of course, you should only do this when you are sure the target host has changed.

Comment: If I remove the known host how do I add it back?

Comment: By connection to it again but you'll be asked for a confirmation, hence the `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false` on first connection if your want to automate.

Comment: thanks for your answer, you should post it so I can choose it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments in my question I was able to figure out the answer. First I had to remove the known host using the command `remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "slave-instance-node-1".` and I also had to set `export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false`.

Then, I had to add the following line to the /etc/ansible/hosts file next to the server name/ip `ansible_user=USERNAME`. And finally I had to add the following line inside the /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg file `private_key_file = /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other commentators, you may check which IP your instances are using. If your DNS is configured for the external IPs, you may prefer static external IP to avoid this error after instance reboot. The external addressees are ephemeral, and the issue may occur not only after redeployment, after reboot also. You may be interested in this doc https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses